# CKEDITOR How to find and wrap text in span

Tags: ckeditor

I am writing a CKEDITOR plugin that needs to wrap certain pieces of text in a  tag. From a webservice, I have an array of items that need to be wrapped. The array is just the plain text strings. Such as:

```
"[best buy", "horrible migraine", "eat cake"]
```

I need to find the instances of this text in the editor and wrap them in a span tag.

This is further complicated because the text may be marked up. So the HTML for "best buy" might be

```
"<strong>best</strong> buy"
```

but the text returned from the web service is stripped of any markup.

I started trying to use a CKEDITOR.htmlParser() object, and that seems like it is moderately successful. I am able to catch the parser.onText event and check if the text contains anything in my array.

But then I cannot modify that text. Modifications are not persisted back to the source html. So I think using the htmlParser() is a dead-end.

What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Oh, and as a bonus, I also do not want to lose my user's current cursor position when the changes are displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to work on a real DOM (not the htmlParser.* tree) and you will need to implement a method which for a given text returns a matching ranges in the DOM. Then you can use `CKEDITOR.style` to wrap these fragments with a style you want and `selection.createBookmarks()` to retain selection position while you're doing this. Lots of coding, but lots of fun too :).

Comment: Thanks, @Reinmar. I got this mostly working using filters. Don't know if this is the best way to do it. But I create a function filter for a new htmlParser, and apply the filter to the html. The function filter knows to check for the text. Then I use editor.document.getBody().setHtml(results); to show the results. Then I have another filter that strips the text back out in the dataProcessor.htmlFilter. ...I'll add this as an "answer" in a bit and you can criticize. :)

Comment: I ended up doing something similar as a widget, that way the user can't change the internal formatting or edit these (although they can still delete them). That may or may not be a concern for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I wound up doing and it seems to be working so far.

I created a text filter rule that searches through my array of items for any item that is contained (or partially contained) in the text. If so, it wraps the element in my span.

A drawback here is that I wind up with two spans for items with markup. But in my usecase, this is tolerable.

Then I set the results using:

```
editor.document.getBody().setHtml(results);
```

Because of this, I also have to strip this markup back out when this text gets read. I do this using an elements filter on editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.

This seems to be working well for my (so far limited) test cases.